# jquery datatimepicker, ограничение по выбору времени

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

У меня есть данный код.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
      minDate: 0
   });
});
```

У меня создается такой input
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне поставить ограничение по времени? Чтобы было с 9:00 утра по 18 00, другое время нельзя было выбрать.

Comment: В документации это прямо на первой странице написано, достаточно просто почитать чуть дальше инициализации, вы удивитесь сколько там инфы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{minTime:0,}// now
{minTime:new Date()}
{minTime:'12:00'}
{minTime:'13:45:34',formatTime:'H:i:s'}

{maxTime:0,}
{maxTime:'12:00'}
{maxTime:'13:45:34',formatTime:'H:i:s'}
```